# integrate only oauth2 in rails app without doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have been check and tested how doorkeeper works. I am new to oauth/oauth2, so I am puzzled if it can work alone without doorkeeper or grape.
    The question is can I create authentication using oauth/oauth2 alone? How can I possible do it. For example, I have a store app and I want to integrate
        oauth2 for my API, how can I possibly do it? Can anybody give me an idea or give some bunch of links of tutorials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found tutorials that my foggy perspective clears. Here are the lists of links:

1. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119225/oauth2-and-authentication
2. https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified
3. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/oauth2-and-so-can-you/
4. https://auth0.com/blog/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-oauth-2-but-were-too-afraid-to-ask/